# How to get an Array with just the values from selected checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I bind checkboxes to an array in my model, so that the array always contains just the values corresponding to the selected checkboxes?

For example, instead of:

```
"groups": { "name1": true, "name2": false, "name3": true }
```

I need to get:

```
 "groups": [ "name1", "name3" ]
```

I browsed through a lot of questions and some answers suggested using `ng-true` for getting custom values, but that does not solve the problem, because then I get:

```
"groups": { "name1": 'CustomvalueIset', "name2": 'CustomValueIset', "name3": 'CustomValueIset' }
```

My current code looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="group">Groups</label><br/>
   <label class="checkboxes-br" data-ng-repeat="group in groups">
       <input type="checkbox" id="group" data-ng-model="model.groups[group.name]">
       {{group.name}}
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. (For example _"I need `groups: {'Valuename', 'Valuename2'}`"_ is both unclear and uses invalid syntax.)

Comment: I need to get that output in my JSON file

Comment: @VladimirJovanovic maybe you meant `"groups": [ "Valuename", "Valuename2" ]` as an array?

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant, I apologize for a bad syntax im a bit in a  hurry typing right now

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support in AngularJS for checkboxes adding/removing values from an array. There cannot be, because form control model-view binding is managed by `ngModel`, which requires the control (input) to bind its value to a separate assignable expression (so there's no way to make `ngModel` *delete* a value when the checkbox is unchecked).

### Don't Mind `undefined`

You can either solve this by making `model.groups` an `Array` and using doing the following code:

```
<label ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.groups[$index]" ng-true-value="group.name" ng-false-value="undefined">
    ...
</label>
```

and then filter out the `undefined`s when using the array.

### Computed Property

Or you can just assign the boolean `true`/`false` values to an object and set a `$watch` on that object that automatically updates your array.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.groupFlags[group.name]">
```

+

```
var groups = $scope.model.groups = [];
$scope.$watch('model.groupFlags', function (flags) {
    groups.length = 0;
    for (var key in flags) {
        groups.push(key);
    }
}, true);
```

---

*Original answer (the question was unclear):*

[The documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) suggests that `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` should work just fine:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-true-value="group.name" ng-false-value="''">
```

Comment: Except they dont. When I use ng-true-value with
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-true-value="group.name" ng-false-value="''">{{group.name}} in my json output I get {{group.name}}.group.name.

Here you are my Git project, its small, run it, check output and youll see https://github.com/BigBadVlada/angular

Comment: Add a group first, then add a site

Comment: I've updated the answer to respond to clarification of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ng-click or cg-change handler that adds/removes values from the array.